# Error when trying to dynamically load PHP library

Tags: php, shared-libraries

When I try to dynamically load a shared PHP library like this

```
dl('libmegaphp.so');
```

I get this error

> PHP Warning:  dl(): Dynamically loaded extensions aren't enabled in

Answer (score 8):

You need to [enable the dl()](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.enable-dl) function in your php.ini

`enable_dl = On`